# How to communcation between web inside webview back to react native apps

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I'm new in React Native.

I need to create communication between RN - Web - RN (RN to Web and then Web back to RN).

Assume i have list of item inside my web that called inside a webview. Each item inside list can be tapped/clicked. When i click one of item inside item list inside my web, i will redirect it to React Native apps page and show detail of realted item.

What i have done until now :
I can inject Javascript from React Native to Webview like this :

```
<WebView
  source={{uri: "myweb.com/webview.php"}}
  injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  style={{height: 100}} />
```

That code can open communication between React Native **to** Webpage inside webview, but i still fail to communication from Web inside webview **to** React Native. Can anyone explain, how to do it (and is it possible?)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use window.postMessage to communicate from Web to RN.

In your injectedJavascript do something like this:

```
const injectedJs = `
  window.postMessage("Your message");
`;
```

(in your case, you will need to find the list DOM elements and use postMessage on every click)

And then on your WebView component read this message like so:

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: "myweb.com/webview.php"}}
    injectedJavaScript={injectedJs}
    startInLoadingState
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    onMessage={event => {
      alert('MESSAGE >>>>' + event.nativeEvent.data);
    }}
/>
```

You can even send a json string as a message.

Comment: So we will use like a "string code" and when React Native receive code from postMessage and then we can navigate to other React Native page ? isn't it ? or we can send navigate instruction directly from Webview ?

Comment: You will send a postMessage from WebView and then you can handle all the RN related actions inside your WebView's onMessage function. What we do in our app is send a json string as a message with actionType and bodyData. Then in our onMessage function we have a switch(actionType) and there we handle the different Views that we need to open inside our App.

Comment: i already try this code. This code working fine in iOS, but not in Android. Nothing happen in Android. Can you explain why?

Comment: When i trace , the problem only appear when you try inject this : const injectedJs = `
  window.postMessage("Your message");
`;

In Android not working, but working if not come from injected script.

Comment: I have put together a snack that displays a basic usage of the postMessage, and works on my android phone. It basically triggers an alert with the loaded url. https://snack.expo.io/B1MDei5aX. I'm sure there are plenty of cases that you would need to tweak this a bit to make it work. For example I noticed that if you make any errors in the injected Javascript then the code doesn't run and there are no errors telling you what is wrong... Maybe you can put together a snack with your example so I can have a look.

Comment: I'm not sure. But i try your snack , and only working when play in iOS, and not working when i change to Android device. (I try using your snack simulator)

Comment: hm... strange, it works for me on android device and on snack. Try making a few clicks inside the webview and see if you get an alert. But this is the method you use to communicate between WebView and RN. We use it successfully in out RN app.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
 import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default function App() {

const html = `
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("hello")
            },1000)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
`;

return (
    <>
    <WebView 
    source = {{ html }}
    onMessage={(event) => {
    alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
    }}
    />
    </>
    );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXMyg.png)